# Magento - Add custom column to RMA grid (Resolutions)

Tags: magento, grid

I need to add a custom column (for resolutions) to RMA grid in Magento.
I'm using the Mirasvit extension for RMA.

File path is app/code/local/Mirasvit/Rma/Block/Adminhtml/Rma/Grid.php

Thanks